# Creating default object from empty value using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update the setting but unfortunately, I am facing an error on how to fix this error? please help me thanks.

please see error https://flareapp.io/share/yPaYdGP4

**Controller**

```
public function settingupdate(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->except('_token','logo_image');
    if ($request->logo_image) {
        $setting = Settings::where('key','logo_image')->first();
        $input['logo_image'] = $request->logo_image;
        $input['logo_image'] = Storage::disk('cms')->putFile('', $request->file('logo_image'));
        $request->file('logo_image');
    }

    foreach($input as $key => $value) {    
        $setting = Settings::where('key',$key)->first();
        $setting->value = $value;
        $setting->save();
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Setting Successfully updated')- >with('path',$setting);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because of below line. This line returning no record and you are setting value on it `$setting->value = $value`

```
$setting = Settings::where('key',$key)->first();
```

To resolve this you can check whether data exist or not

```
    $setting = Settings::where('key',$key)->first();
    if ($setting !== null) { // add this
        $setting->value = $value;
        $setting->save();
    }
```